# PDF creation - Tags - Authouring

Tags: language-agnostic, cross-platform

This is so vague it's ridiculous but who knows...

We have got this client who will not budge - they are supplying PDF files auto generated by their own software.  These files don't import into our (printing) lab management software - made by kodak.

So I emailed Kodak the error log and relevant files and got this back..

*DP2 supports the importing of PDF's from –        Adobe Illustrator   and  Quark Express 
Some of the capabilities when importing PDF's as ORDER ITEMS  is that the images can be modified, 
color corrected, or replaced.   To accomplish this, the PDF is disassembled.   PDF's from Illustrator and Quark, 
contain additional information that tells us where everythings goes and how, thus enought information for 
us to reassemble the PDF.   While other applications do generate PDF's they don't contain this additional 
information.*

After speaking with a 3rd party 'expert' we need to consider another 3rd party 'rip' software that's fairly expensive.  So before I go ahead I thought I'd ask if any one has experience with this stuff?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Thats a tough one, PDFs can be created in so many different ways, it hard to tell exactly what any given PDF may be composed of, personally I'd try some different PDF editors first to see if you can exact the data you need before going the expensive route.

Eg Foxit PDF offer an editor (I think its free, or cheap in any case)

**Darknight**